# Как убрать модальное окно?

Tags: javascript

Добрый день!
Подскажите, что не так)
Есть форма - два поля и сабмит. Если в полях что-то есть, то данные отправляются, а пользователь перенаправляется на другую страницу. Код следующий:

```
function valid_n_leave(){
   if(document.getElementById("userphone").value && document.getElementById("username").value){
    window.location.assign("http://ripstore.loc/eskiz.html");
   }        
}
```

И все бы ничего, но перед тем как редиректнуть, открывается модальное окно и в нём нолик (0). Подскажите, как его убрать? Ну то есть, как сделать, что бы его и не было) Спасибо[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не закрывайте. Пригодится под ответ о способах отладки.

Comment: Ищите alert в коде. Тот код что Вы привели не может генерировать это сообщение.

Comment: Покажите весь код или дайте ссылку на страницу. Возможно, где-то в  onbeforeunload или onunload вписан алерт.

Comment: Пожалуйста, любая форма с сайта http://ripstore.com.ua/

Comment: UPD:  окно выводится только в браузере Chrome

Comment: <form id="form-2"  class="form-name-phone">
      <div class="form-item text">Получите БЕСПЛАТНУЮ консультацию<br/><span>Мы перезвоним вам в течение 15 минут</span></div>
      <div class="form-item"><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Введите имя:"/></div>
      <div class="form-item"><input type="text" name="userphone" placeholder="Введите телефон:"/></div>
      <div class="form-item"><input type="submit" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Other_Pages', 'Order_Confirm');" value="Получить скидку"/></div>
    </form>

Comment: Значит в хроме и сделай то, что я описал.

Answer (score 3):

Ищешь в коде этот вызов alert и разбираешься с ним.

Найти можно, например, так: открываешь консоль браузера, выполняешь

```
window.alert = function () { debugger }
```

после чего делаешь то, что приводит к появлению alert'а. Браузер остановится на команде `debugger`, а тебе будет доступен стек вызовов, по которому ты сможешь найти интересующий тебя код.

Answer (score 2):

Почему бы не использовать `location.href = 'http://ripstore.loc/eskiz.html'`, вместо `window.location.assign`? Вызов функции работает медленее, чем доступ до объекта.

```
function valid_n_leave(){
   if(document.getElementById("userphone").value && document.getElementById("username").value){
    location.href = 'http://ripstore.loc/eskiz.html';
   }        
}
```